# Moving rows in a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm trying to use the `move_columns` function from the `sjmisc` package. However I'm having a problem in that when I use numerals I get a different result from the one I get when I use variables standing for those indices. For example I want to move the column `Petal.Width` to position 3 (so after 2), but when I use variables it gets moved to the end of the data frame.

```
> library(sjmisc)
> 
> data(iris)
> head(iris)
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa
> 
> index_rec<-4
> index<-2
> one<-move_columns(iris,index_rec,.after=index)
> head(one)
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Species Petal.Width
1          5.1         3.5          1.4  setosa         0.2
2          4.9         3.0          1.4  setosa         0.2
3          4.7         3.2          1.3  setosa         0.2
4          4.6         3.1          1.5  setosa         0.2
5          5.0         3.6          1.4  setosa         0.2
6          5.4         3.9          1.7  setosa         0.4
> 
> two<-move_columns(iris,4,.after=2)
> head(two)
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Width Petal.Length Species
1          5.1         3.5         0.2          1.4  setosa
2          4.9         3.0         0.2          1.4  setosa
3          4.7         3.2         0.2          1.3  setosa
4          4.6         3.1         0.2          1.5  setosa
5          5.0         3.6         0.2          1.4  setosa
6          5.4         3.9         0.4          1.7  setosa
```

The [documentation](https://rdrr.io/cran/sjmisc/man/move_columns.html) says that if neither of `.before` or `.after` are specified, the column is moved to the end of the data frame by default. So is the problem in the first case that I'm not specifying `.after`? I think it's clearly there...

Comment: Yes, sorry. It still doesn't work.

Comment: Created an issue on github for this - https://github.com/strengejacke/sjmisc/issues/138

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**

It works with quasi-quotation.

```
library(sjmisc)

index_rec<-4
index <- 2

move_columns(iris,4,.after=!!index) %>% head

#  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Width Petal.Length Species
#1          5.1         3.5         0.2          1.4  setosa
#2          4.9         3.0         0.2          1.4  setosa
#3          4.7         3.2         0.2          1.3  setosa
#4          4.6         3.1         0.2          1.5  setosa
#5          5.0         3.6         0.2          1.4  setosa
#6          5.4         3.9         0.4          1.7  setosa
```

---

**Earlier Answer**

It seems like a bug to me when you pass the number as a variable to the function.

```
#This works fine
move_columns(iris,4,.after=2) %>% head

# Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Width Petal.Length Species
#1          5.1         3.5         0.2          1.4  setosa
#2          4.9         3.0         0.2          1.4  setosa
#3          4.7         3.2         0.2          1.3  setosa
#4          4.6         3.1         0.2          1.5  setosa
#5          5.0         3.6         0.2          1.4  setosa
#6          5.4         3.9         0.4          1.7  setosa

#This doesn't
move_columns(iris,4,.after=index) %>% head

#  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Species Petal.Width
#1          5.1         3.5          1.4  setosa         0.2
#2          4.9         3.0          1.4  setosa         0.2
#3          4.7         3.2          1.3  setosa         0.2
#4          4.6         3.1          1.5  setosa         0.2
#5          5.0         3.6          1.4  setosa         0.2
#6          5.4         3.9          1.7  setosa         0.4
```

Why not use the new `relocate` function from `dplyr`? It does not have a bug and works as expected when passed a variable.

```
library(dplyr)

relocate(iris, 4, .after=2) %>% head

#  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Width Petal.Length Species
#1          5.1         3.5         0.2          1.4  setosa
#2          4.9         3.0         0.2          1.4  setosa
#3          4.7         3.2         0.2          1.3  setosa
#4          4.6         3.1         0.2          1.5  setosa
#5          5.0         3.6         0.2          1.4  setosa
#6          5.4         3.9         0.4          1.7  setosa

relocate(iris,index_rec,.after=index) %>% head

#  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Width Petal.Length Species
#1          5.1         3.5         0.2          1.4  setosa
#2          4.9         3.0         0.2          1.4  setosa
#3          4.7         3.2         0.2          1.3  setosa
#4          4.6         3.1         0.2          1.5  setosa
#5          5.0         3.6         0.2          1.4  setosa
#6          5.4         3.9         0.4          1.7  setosa
```